# Overflowing background color from header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My header background color overflows past the page. I am wondering how to adjust its width so that it automatically fills whatever screen size without overflowing. I assume this has something to do with my width property on the "white" class, or because it is within a container. Basically it causes a horizontal scroll due to the background color extending, instead of just stopping at 100% width of the page. I appreciate any help I get for this, thanks a lot.

```css
    .white {
        background-color: #fff;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .white:before {
        content: "";
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 200vw;
        left: -100vw;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg white row">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="{% static 'accounts/logo/logo.png' %}" height="40" width="40">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Search Box -->
                <div class="search_wrapper">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search_input">
                    <button class="search_button">&#128269;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Nav List -->
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <span class="middle">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <img src="{% static 'accounts/blah/blah.png' %}" height="20" width="20" id="home"> Random
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <img src="{% static 'accounts/blah/blah.png' %}" height="20" width="20" id="lessons"> Random
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <img src="{% static 'accounts/blah/blah.png' %}" height="30" width="30" id="teacher"> Random
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <img src="{% static 'accounts/icons/blue.png' %}" height="20" width="30" id="msg"> Random
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </span>

                    <!-- Avatar Dropdown -->
                    <span class="right">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="{% static 'accounts/blah/blah.png' %}" height="30" width="25"> Blah
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Random</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Random</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Random</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Random</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </span>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is vanilla CSS without bootstrap since this is what I'm using.
I can't guarantee that this works the same with bootstrap.

You are trying to use

```
width: 200vw;
```

since 1vw is relative to 1% of the width of the viewport you are giving your content a width of 2 times the width of th viewport.

```
width: 100vw;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

should make it span the whole width of the screen.
You just have to make sure that there are no paddings or margins either on the left or tight side.

Here a small refreshment for the units.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

---

You could also try some negative margin:

```
.white {
    background-color: #343434;
    position: relative;
    width:100vw;
    margin: -10px;
}
```

should work fine for you
codepen: https://codepen.io/ironlors/pen/bjYOpQ

Comment: Doesn't work. The background color doesn't overflow anymore; however, it stops before getting to 100% width of the page.

Comment: did you check for any margins or padding on the right/left?

Comment: The container it is in had paddings and margins, but I need the header within the container since it's best aligned with the rest of the content like that.

Comment: added an idea about negative margin to answer

Comment: Didn't fix it. Just slightly moved the header to the left and up.

Comment: I am sry it seems like I don't get the issue. You want to get rid of the whitespace before and after the header right? And also this horizontal scrolling should disappear.  I just might not get the question. Since  `width:100vw;` in combination with removing padding/margin should solve this. Maybe a screenshot or the code of the whole webpage would also be a nice addition for me.

Comment: Basically, I want all the text on my page whether it be the nav or main, to be aligned with each other (so I need the margins and padding), and then just the background color of the header to expand full width past the containers.

Comment: ok then I would again just use ´margin-left:-8px;´ and `padding-left:8px;` on the header. This extends the background 8px to the left (default `<body>` margin) while keeping the content at the same spot

Answer (score 1):

Use `<div class="container-fluid">` instead of `<div class="container">`

Comment: I don't want my page to fully expand depending on screen size, this can cause a problem for 4k screens or large sizes. Also, it is not how I want the site to look aesthetically. I want all the content to be how it is, but just the background colour of the nav to expand to the full size.

Comment: In that case add the container inside the `nav` tags

Comment: That would end the container when the nav ends. I want the container to continue the structure with my body content outside of <nav> as well.

Comment: Use another container for the rest of the page. Since the same css rules apply to both them, the size will match that of the `nav` container.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the text I have in my nav not be aligned with the main content, since it would be container fluid. Basically, I want all the text on my page whether it be the nav or main, to be aligned with each other, and then just the background color of the header to expand full width past the containers.